# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, web

I'm getting this error when my web is trying to load mp3 audio from a resource

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED

**PHP CODE**

```
  <?php if ($name == "audio") : ?>
              <audio class="center" id="audio"   controls   controlsList="nodownload">
                  <source src="../audio/myAudioPlayer.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                  </audio>
              <?php endif; ?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did the file exist in the path you are using **../audio/myAudioPlayer.mp3** ?

Comment: what if you disable the cache on chrome , does the error still there ?

Comment: _“What am i doing wrong?”_ - maybe nothing … There seems to be a Chrome bug in connection with byte-range requests (which can be expected to happen for larger, binary resources such as an mp3 file) & caching - https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent/issues/1193, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543367